# left join which will return all records in table 1 and add columns from table 2

Tags: mysql, join

I am new to MySQL having previously done everything in MS Access. I am trying to join together 2 tables so that I can show all of the records from Table1 and add in certain columns from Table2.

I can join the tables together using

```
SELECT Table1.Field1, Table2.Field2, Table3.Field3
 FROM Table1
 LEFT JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.Field1=Table2.Field21
```

However firstly I get blanks showing for Field1 when I do this even though all of the fields are populated.

I then want to add in two further fields from Table2 into my results...

Comment: You know, having the title completely in uppercase letters does not attract more readers, it may even have the opposite effect.

Comment: Apologies. I was unaware of the etiquette...

Comment: No problem. Your question is not quite clear to me (which may also be the main reason for the downvotes apart from the uppercase thing). It's always a good idea to include sample data and desired result based on the sample data.

Comment: OK. I've reposted it (lower case title and slightly changed) so hopefully it will be a bit clearer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Left Join returning more records than in Table 1 and adding in additional data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930770/left-join-returning-more-records-than-in-table-1-and-adding-in-additional-data)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

SELECT Table1.Field1, Table2.Field2, Table2.*
 FROM Table1
 LEFT JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.Field1=Table2.Field2

Comment: I've just realised that I've even entered the query incorrectly. My eyes are going square. I'll start it again I think. Thanks for trying to help!