# Left Join returning more records than in Table 1 and adding in additional data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am new to MySQL having previously done everything in MS Access. I am trying to join together 2 tables so that I can show all of the records from Table1 and add in certain columns from Table2.

I can join the tables together using

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.Address, Table1.TelephoneNumber
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.TelephoneNumber=Table2.PhoneNumber
```

Table1 has 3900 records and Table2 almost 7million

I then want to add in (for example) PostTown and PostCode from Table2. So that my query will return

Table1.Name, Table1.Address, Table1.TelephoneNumber, Table2.PostTown, Table2.PostCode

How do I make the query only return everything in Table1 but show matches from Table2 where it has some and blanks where it hasn't. There are some blank values in the Table2.PhoneNumber which I think are duplicating in my results as it returns almost a million rows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have blanks in your data (not nulls):

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.Address, Table1.TelephoneNumber
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.TelephoneNumber = Table2.PhoneNumber
  AND Table1.TelephoneNumber != ''
```

Checking for `NOT NULL` won't help, because null is not equal to null (whereas blank is equal to blank)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.Address, Table1.TelephoneNumber
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.TelephoneNumber=Table2.PhoneNumber
WHERE Table1.TelephoneNumber IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.Address, Table1.TelephoneNumber FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.TelephoneNumber=Table2.PhoneNumber
where Table1.TelephoneNumber is not null
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. That still returns the same as the null values are in Table2.PhoneNumber. Even if I do WHERE Table2.PhoneNumber is not null then I still get a massive return

Comment: You can change the where condition as following Isnull(Table1.TelephoneNumber,0) <> 0 ( or != 0 )

Comment: Thanks again. I have a solution now below from Bohemian

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.Address, Table1.TelephoneNumber, Table2.PostTown, Table2.PostCode
    FROM Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table2
       ON Table1.TelephoneNumber=Table2.PhoneNumber

Identify all the data that you need in the SELECT statement, not just the data in Table 1. 
The join will match up the correct data between the tables.